# MySql query two fields together in results

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following table:

```
retailer    register    store
1           104         b
1           101         a
2           104         b
2           101         a
3           104         b
3           101         a
```

I am looking to query the table to get a result that looks like:

```
retailer  register  store  
1 _ 101, 104 _ a, b  
2 _ 101, 104 _ a, b  
3 _ 101, 104 _ a, b
```

Comment: Are your commas in the expected result meant to represent a column separator, or is it literally a string of all the results comma-separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use group_concat and group by

```
 select 
    retailer
 , group_concat(register ORDER BY registed ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
 , group_concat(store ORDER BY store ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
 from my_table 
 group by retailer
```

and if you need the saparator you should use a concat

```
 select 
      concat ( retailer
      , '_'
      ,  group_concat(register ORDER BY registed ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
      , '_'
      , group_concat(store ORDER BY store ASC SEPARATOR ', '))
 from my_table 
 group by retailer
```

Comment: you result  will be different

Comment: @RaminDarvishov   .  explain better

Comment: your result will be different order and without seperator

Comment: ',' (comma) is default seperator  but user want comma with space

Comment: @RaminDarvishov   if this is what you need the asnwer is updated  and also there is a '_'  between the column  .. concatenated

Comment: please see my answer and result

Comment: now your first sql code is right and it is same with my code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by and GROUP_CONCAT with ORDER BY and SEPERATOR

```
select retailer, 
GROUP_CONCAT(register ORDER BY register DESC SEPARATOR ', ') AS register, 
GROUP_CONCAT(store ORDER BY store DESC SEPARATOR ', ') AS store
from my_table 
GROUP BY retailer

retailer  register  store  
   1      101, 104   a, b  
   2      101, 104   a, b  
   3      101, 104   a, b
```